# NSCFNumber escapedString Error with a NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsnumber

So I'm getting this error when creating a `NSDictionary`:

```
DLog(@"hiliteID: %@ | regionID: %@", hiliteID, regionID);

if ([hiliteID isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    DLog(@"hititeID is a number");
}
if ([hiliteID isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    DLog(@"hiliteID is a string");
}
if ([regionID isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    DLog(@"regionID is a number");
}
if ([regionID isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    DLog(@"regionID is a string");
}

NSDictionary *regionDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:regionID forKey:hiliteID];
DLog(@"regionDictionary: %@", regionDictionary);

id result = [self.serverCall XMLRPCCall:kSaveHilitedObjects withObjects:@[self.mapContext, regionDictionary]];
```

What is logged:

```
DEBUG | hiliteID: 160399 | regionID: 950
DEBUG | hititeID is a number
DEBUG | regionID is a number
DEBUG | regionDictionary: {
    160399 = 950;
}
DEBUG -[__NSCFNumber escapedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7947f5d0
DEBUG *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber escapedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7947f5d0'
```

`0x7947f5d0` has a value of 160399 so it is `hiliteID`.

`hiliteID` is a returned value from our server and is set as a `NSString`. I cast it to a `NSNumber`:

```
NSArray *hiliteIDs = [result allKeys];

if ([[hiliteIDs firstObject] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[hiliteIDs firstObject] integerValue]];
}
else if ([[hiliteIDs firstObject] isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
    return [hiliteIDs firstObject];
}
```

As far as I know, there is no issue with what I am doing here.

the line:

```
id result = [self.serverCall XMLRPCCall:kSaveHilitedObjects withObjects:@[self.mapContext, regionDictionary]];
```

I've used this class dozens of times in the code and never had an issue.

What can be causing the error?

Comment: If you overwrite the values of `regionDictionary` with hardcoded `NSString` or `NSNumber` key/values does it still crash?

Comment: @Larme Yes, I still get the same error.

Comment: If you get the error with `NSString` and also with NSNumber, could be another parameter that is causing the issue. Check the value of each var.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
reason: '-[__NSCFNumber escapedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7947f5d0'
```

Someone trying to call -escapedString method from NSNumber class, so it seems like the problem is that you passing NSNumber argument when NSString required. Try to use only NSString values inside your NSDictionary.

Comment: The server requires them to be `NSNumber` values though.

Comment: This doesn't matter because 'XMLRPCCall:withObjects', as you can see from error message, converts all parameters to escaped strings before sending.

Comment: You are right. I didn't think that far down the line. I set the key to a string and left the value as a number and it works. The parser I guess can't handle NSNumber keys. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever `XMLRPCCall:withObjects:` is calling an invalid method. I would recommend making all inputs into this method into `NSStrings` so that that call doesn't internally call methods on `NSNumbers` that `NSNumber` isn't capable of responding to.

```
NSString *regionIDString = [regionID stringValue];
NSString *hiliteIDString = [hiliteID stringValue];
NSDictionary *regionDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:regionIDString forKey:hiliteIDString];
```